# Are more rejected reviews than accepts normal in suggested edits?

Tags: discussion, review-queues, suggested-edits

I've been reviewing a lot of suggested edits recently and I like to see how my stats measure up to other reviewers. However I have been noticing that a lot of reviewers have ~10 times more accepts than rejects. I know the queues are polluted with robo-reviewers but the amount of people I see with these statistics is astronomically high.

My reviews are currently at:

> approved 269 edit suggestions and rejected 306 edit suggestions and improved 125 edit suggestions

Are these stats normal, excluding robo-reviewers? Or am I reviewing to harshly?

Comment: How many reviews do you skip? If you handle every review, then it's quite a high rejection-rate. If you skip a lot and leave the good edits to the robo-approvers it's ok.

Comment: Yes, the number of robo-reviewers is indeed astronomically high. It is not a problem to have more rejects than accepts. Many suggested edits are terrible or simply not an improvement, and *should* be rejected.

Comment: @Floern I'd say I skip 10 in every 30 or something along those lines at least. Sometimes a lot higher, sometimes a lot lower.

Comment: I'm currently at 440 approve to 1031 reject. But that is because I often skip reviews of edits that seem OK to me. Edits get apporved easy enough - too much get accepted that should not. So i try to use my limited number of reviews in an attempt to stop at least some of the worst....